# Managing Quota In Kafka Confluent Cloud

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, quota, confluent-cloud

I've been reading the documentation on Confluent Cloud (Not the Confluent Platform) and couldn't find a way to manage network and request quotas.
Is this not supported in Confluent Cloud ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't supported at the moment.